# NetworkManager - detect client disconnecting

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, dhcp

I'm using `journalctl -fu NetworkManager.service` to detect clients connecting to my access-point. I do however not see anything when clients disconnect. Is this possible?
Is it a limitation of DHCP?

Linux 4.15.0-74-generic
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: There is a multitude of ways a wireless client might disconnect. While a perfectly ideal client might first relinquish its DHCP lease and then deauthenticate/dissociate from the wireless network, this may not always happen. Clients might also just switch off their radio, move out of range, or run out of battery power unexpectedly: these are just a few reasons that might make a controlled disconnect impossible. The process managing the wireless access point functionality at the lowest level (`hostapd`?) might have the most accurate list of clients that are known to be actually present.

Comment: DHCP logs only show DHCP events. Client connection will create an event if the client isn't using a static IP. Since the dynamic IP has a lease it won't log when the client disconnects; DHCP can only log when the lease expires or is freed. What you're looking for are association / authorization events. Does "my access point" refer to a hotspot you created on the Linux system or an actual, external AP?

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yes, it is the Ubuntu machine creating a hotspot with NetworkManager. Through testing I found that `wpa_supplicant` is logging to `/var/log/syslog` both `AP-STA-DISCONNECTED` and `AP-STA-CONNECTED`. Will have to test other scenarios as @telcoM describes. Maybe there is a heartbeat implemented?

Comment: No, there's no hearbeat or anything similar. But assuming your Ubuntu's connecting to internet with cable, those are the client connection/disconnection events you were looking for :-) You can identify the clients by their MAC addresses. I'd check `wpa_supplicant` documentation to find a way to direct those in a separate logfile instead of the syslog.